# Frequency function in C

Tags: c

I wrote a program that should take a string and a letter, then call a function which have two parameters (the string, the letter) and then count frequency of letter in the string.

The problem with my code is that it always returns `num` with value zero for any letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Occur(char [], char);

int main()
{
    char s[100], l;
    printf("Enter A String:\n");
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("Enter A Letter:\n");
    scanf("%c",&l);
    getchar();

    printf("Num Of Occurance is %d ",Occur(s,l));

    return 0;
}

int Occur(char S[100], char L)
{
    int i;
    int num=0;

    for(i=0; S[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(S[i]==L)
        num++;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Your problem is not the counting function, but how you read input. `%s` snacs a single word and `%c` scans the next character, which very likely is a space or newline. You can skip whitespace by preceding `%c` with a space: `scanf(" %c",&l);`

Comment: (Note: It might be a good idea to include the character to count in the message. That would point you to the problem.)

Comment: @MOehm You are Right .. Brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason of problem :

`scanf("%c",&l)          //Here %c takes enter key of scanf("%s",s);`;

So, there are mainly 2 solution to your problem:

**Sol. 1**     => `scanf(" %c",&l)           //use whitespace before %c`

**Sol. 2**    =>   Use  *fflush(stdin)* that flushes the output buffer of a stream.

```
int main()
{

char s[100],l;
printf("Enter A String:\n");
scanf("%s",s);
printf("Enter A Letter:\n");
fflush(stdin);                       //here fflush(stdin) used to flushes the output buffer.
scanf("%c",&l);
l = getchar();
......
......
}
```

**NOte:** Since fflush(stdin) has  undefined behavior so, always use priority to Solution 1 , instead of fflush().  :)

Comment: About fflush look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Answer (score 5):

First, you should have tried debugging your code. If you would have done it, you would have seen that the letter you thought L holds is not what L actually holds.

Second, your problem is simple, L is not getting the letter you enter because of the enter from the string before is stuck in the scanf buffer... use `scanf (" %c")` [with preceeding whitespace] to resolve.

As mentioned in other answers, there are other solutions like the unrecommended `fflush()`. An alternative that is not considered harmful is `getchar()` between the `scanf("%s")` and the `scanf("%c")`. That will give you the same effect as using `scanf(" %c");`

The reason that all of these methods work is because they all consume the last `char` (which is, in your case the `\n`) stuck in the buffer, and thus allowing the `%c` to consume the `char` you actually intend to read

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is wrong in terms of good code practices.

Instead of

```
int Occur(char S[100], char L)
```

You should write it as

```
int Occur(char S[] , char L)
```

because otherwise your code would specifically look to accept strings of size not more than 100 chars.

Apart from that as Ilario Pierbattista said its a input buffer problem.
The stdin needs to get cleared before taking further input, hence the juggad of putting scanf before a getchar() call would work.

Comment: that is not correct. The problem lies in getting the character from input. Declaration and definition of a function are fine

Comment: @CIsForCookies the post you mentioned discusses function prototype not the definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's an input buffer problem. The char is read by `getchar` instead of `scanf`.
Doing `l = getchar()` solves the problem (the call of `scanf` just before clears the input buffer).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Occur(char [],char);


int main()
{

char s[100],l;
printf("Enter A String:\n");
scanf("%s",s);
printf("Enter A Letter:\n");
scanf("%c",&l);
l = getchar();

printf("Num Of Occurance is %d ",Occur(s,l));


return 0;
}


int Occur(char S[100],char L){

int i;
int num=0;

for(i=0;S[i]!='\0';i++){

if(S[i]==L)
    num++;
}

return num;

}
```